# Module Versioning Best Practices

Tags: module, magento-1, versioning

I realize that this mayb be a subjective question, but is there anything from the core team or code itself that expresses good versioning practices for Magento modules?

Specifically, because of the naming convention of SQL upgrade scripts on modules (eg: `mysql4-upgrade-0.0.3-0.0.4.php`, I'm wondering if module versioning should be dependent upon database interaction. In other words, should I only increment my module's version as new upgrade scripts are added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code point of view it will does not really matter. For example if you have the version 1.5.0 as the last set-up script of your module but have a version 1.6.0 without script. You can then move directly to 1.7.0 with a set-up script and it should not cause issues.

The code will check the following.

1. The current version in the database: `$dbVer = $this->_getResource()->getDbVersion($this->_resourceName);`
2. The current version in your module config file: `$configVer = (string)$this->_moduleConfig->version;`

From these two values it will then decide to run update scripts or not.

```
 $status = version_compare($configVer, $dbVer);
 switch ($status) {
    case self::VERSION_COMPARE_LOWER:
        $this->_rollbackResourceDb($configVer, $dbVer);
        break;
    case self::VERSION_COMPARE_GREATER:
        $this->_upgradeResourceDb($dbVer, $configVer);
        break;
    default:
        return true;
        break;
 }
```

As part of the call to `_upgradeResourceDB` Magento will use the functions `_getAvailableDbFiles` and `_getAvailableDataFiles`. These functions will look for any update scripts in between the version stored in the database and the version stored in your config.xml file.

So in conclusion it should be safe to skip numbers.

Comment: what an answer :) upvote from me

Comment: For those traveling along the way, here's a related article that gives some more insight into setup scripts and versioning: http://vinaikopp.com/2014/11/03/magento-setup-scripts/

Answer (score 2):

In theory you should change the version number when every you make any change to your module so that you don't have the same version number with different code (ie. bug report, check if a site running the latest version). If you make changes to your module but didn't make any db changes then you could create a empty upgrade script with

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->endSetup();
```

But if you have a module that you only use on 1 site then you can skip the additional overhead and make your changes without change the version number.

Comment: ., you've also made some good points on the theoretical side, but I preferred the depth of David's answer. Thanks for your input!